# Rails 4.1 enum query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am seeing Rails generate the wrong query value when I use an enum col value in a where clause, like this (self added for clarity). **dominant_product_strategy** is an enum.

```
def some_model_method_on_myModel
   MyModel.where(dominant_product_strategy: self.dominant_product_strategy)
end
```

This produces the correct value (again, self just added for clarity):

```
MyModel.where(dominant_product_strategy: self.attributes["dominant_product_strategy"])
```

I'm guessing that Rails sees the enum as a string, and then converts to a integer value of zero. Ughhhhh!

Am I missing something?

This also works:

```
MyModelwhere(dominant_product_strategy: MyModel.dominant_product_strategies[dominant_product_strategy])
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be that you have answered your question by yoursef. Enum variables is a hash:

```
{str1: int1, str2: int2, ...}
```

The value (integer) is storing in DB, and the string is just representation of the int value. When you call `self.dominant_product_strategy`, you get the representation (string) of `dominant_product_strategy` column storing as integer in DB.

I think that your first working solution (self.attributes["dominant_product_strategy"]) is fine.